# Better Confluence Page Index Macro?

Tags: macros, confluence

I'm currently using Confluence Page Index Macro to index my sub-pages from a specific area. The issue is, I can't customize the results generated by this macro.

I would like to have only specific pages with a dedicated tag as a result.

The question is: does exist a better page index macro? I want to have the same output but with less content.

regards!

Comment: Did you mean the *Confluence* page index macro?

Comment: yes! sorry, I'm worrking with JIRA and Confluence at the same moment. Thanks for correctiong me :)